# How to remove the end value in a linked list in C#

Tags: c#, list, variables, linked-list

I need to create a program that will add 2 numbers that are in 2 separate linked lists. I made the program work but I get an extra -1 value on the end which I do not need. How do I get rid of it? Here's some context:

```
/*
  Definition for singly-linked list.
  public class ListNode {
      public int val;
      public ListNode next;
      public ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        int a, k = 0;
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(-1), curr = l3;
        do
        {
            if(k == 1)
                a = l1.val + l2.val + 1;
            else
                a = l1.val + l2.val;
            k = 0;
            if(a >= 10){
                curr.val = a - 10;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
                curr.val = a;
            l1 = l1.next; l2 = l2.next;
            curr.next = new ListNode(-1);
            curr = curr.next;
        }while(l1 != null && l2 != null);
        return l3;
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarification: you're representing each digit in the two numbers as a value in a linked list node, with the linked lists starting with the "ones" values? So you walk through the two numbers digit by digit, "carrying the one"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood properly your problem, I think it is because you're creating a new node at the end of the cycle. In this line:

```
curr.next = new ListNode(-1);
```

By creating a new node right at the end of the `do...while` cycle, the last node in the list will always contain that `-1`. What you want is to evaluate if the termination condition has been met before creating a new node.

Try the code below instead, in which I have passed the creation of new nodes to post-condition:

```
public class Solution {
    public ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(-1), curr = l3;

        for(int a=0, k = 0; l1 != null && l2 != null ; curr.next = new ListNode(-1), curr = curr.next) 
        {
            if(k == 1)
                a = l1.val + l2.val + 1;
            else
                a = l1.val + l2.val;
            k = 0;
            if(a >= 10){
                curr.val = a - 10;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
                curr.val = a;

            l1 = l1.next; l2 = l2.next;
        }
        return l3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider other edge case like what if one number has more digit than the other one. l1 = 7 -> 5 and l2 = 8 -> 6 -> 5

```
private static ListNode AddTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2)
    {
        if (l1 == null) return l2;
        if (l2 == null) return l1;
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(-1), cur = l3;
        int a, k = 0;
        while (l1 != null || l2 != null)
        {
            if (k == 1)
                a = (l1 == null ? 0 : l1.val) + (l2 == null ? 0 : l2.val) + 1;
            else
                a = (l1 == null ? 0 : l1.val) + (l2 == null ? 0 : l2.val);
            k = 0;
            if (a >= 10)
            {
                cur.val = a - 10;
                k = 1;
            }
            else
                cur.val = a;
            l1 = l1?.next;
            l2 = l2?.next;
            if (l1 == null && l2 == null)
                break;
            cur.next = new ListNode(-1);
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        if (k == 1)
            cur.next = new ListNode(1);
        return l3;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution but the program still has some flaws.         Your input
[1]
[9, 9]
Output
[0,10]
Expected
[0,0,1]

Comment: Thanks for pining out that @VukMC. Considered mentioned edge case.